# How to use useRef when element is inside condition?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The problem is that useRef is triggered during first render.
Two examples when it could be a problem.

> 1. When one can have some loading

```
const Problem1 = () => {  
 const ref = useRef();

 if (loading)    
     return null;

 return <input ref={ref} value={} />;

}
```

> 2. When ref is inside some condition.

```
const Problem2 = () => {
 const ref = useRef();

 return user ? <input ref={ref} value={user.name} /> : <Exit >;

}
```

sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-feynman-z68k0

In the second case I at least could show element at the beginning with display: none. But how to solve first problem I have no idea.

What are the best practices in these cases?

Comment: What is the problem? There is no problem that "useRef is triggered during first render". It's ok to have ref without value

Comment: Ok, I didn't mean that it is a problem of useRef, just that I don't know how to use it with these cases. So, how to get correct references in second case when user is false at the first rendering?

Comment: You asking about how to use and you not showing examples of uses

Comment: Ok, if you don't understand what I am talking about, I can add an example. Added!

Comment: Your example doesn't clarify what the problem is. Ref represents a currently displayed element. If the element is not displayed, then you don't have value in ref. Do you want to get access to DOM element which is not attached to document DOM?

Comment: I just wanted to know how would you rewrite code when you need to have ref on element in component when this element is not showed at the first rendering.

Answer (score 5):

See if this works for you:

From React DOCS: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> **useRef()**
>
> However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.
>
> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will **give you the same ref object on every render.**

The `useRef` object won't change across renders. You'll always have the same reference for the `useRef` object with a `current` property. What may change is what you are keeping inside that `current` property.

```js
function App() {

  const input1_ref = React.useRef(null);
  const input2_ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [showInput2, setShowInput2] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    input1_ref.current ?
      console.log('Input1 has been mounted...')
    : console.log('Input1 has NOT been mounted...');
    input2_ref.current ?
      console.log('Input2 has been mounted...')
    : console.log('Input2 has NOT been mounted...');
  });
  

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Input 1</div>
      <input type='text' ref={input1_ref}/>
      {showInput2 &&
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>Input 2</div>
          <input type='text' ref={input2_ref}/>
        </React.Fragment>
      }
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>setShowInput2((prevState)=>!prevState)}>Click</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I thought that useRef can't be changed after first rendering. Need read more docs instead of videos on youtube)). Sorry for bad explanation of problem.

Comment: No problem. The object won't change. What might change is what you decide to keep in the `current` property of the object. `current` is the actual name of the property. That's why you access it with `some_ref.current`

Answer (score 1):

When your conditional element gets assigned to ref.current, it doesn't cause a rerender. You can use a `useCallback` instead, which will run a callback when the element gets rendered:

```js
const Problem2 = () => {
 const ref = useCallback(node = () => {
  ...callback code here
 });

 // Code here won't rerun for a change in ref.current

 return user ? <input ref={ref} value={user.name} /> : <Exit >;
}
```

If you want the whole code of Problem2 to run again (now with a reference to ref), you can add a useState:

```js
const Problem2 = () => {
 const [myInput, setMyInput] = useState(null)
 const ref = useCallback(node => {
  setMyInput(node)
 });

 // Now any code here will run twice, once for myInput
 // equals null, and once when it points to the element

 return user ? <input ref={ref} value={user.name} /> : <Exit >;
}
```