# How to set useRef for html element manually after mounting

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

For context, I have a react app with a tree explorer. When the user hovers a node, I show a menu for 5 seconds using a setTimeout inside a useEffect. I want to be able to set a ref on a file input element in the menu but the ref is always null. How can I update the ref after it has been mounted? The issue it seems is that the input is not mounted until the tree node is hovered but the component the input node is created in has already been mounted.

------------- EDIT -----------

The following code snippet works. The key seems to be the `e.stopPropagation()`. I thought a `ref` would have been a better choice but it did not seem to work.

```js
// component
 
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowControls(false);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [showControls]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log('handleChange...');
  }

  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const el = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    el.click();
  };


  // some other code...

  return (
    //...other jsx

    { showControls && (
      <>
        <IconButton onClick={onButtonClick} />
        <input
          id="hiddenFileInput"
          type="file"
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          onChange={handleChange}
          style={{display: 'none'}}
        />
      </>
    )}
  );
```

Comment: Does this thread answers your question ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134357/9691776

Comment: hey thanks for your help but no it does not.

Comment: Sorry, but what stops you from moving the <input> outside of the conditional rendering block? Asuming it has `display:none`. Ref will be set, no UI changes. But generally - it will be easier and cleaner to move this block to a separate component to be honest. Also + to reusability

Comment: Yeah that is a good point Sergey. I guess I just have my functional composition hat on: keeping the element where it belongs structurally but I guess it can be anywhere inside the component if dispay is none. Thanks for the perspective!